# How to check current user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to know how can I check if the current user has any order or not? if have show the list and if not show the message?

currently I'm using this but it doesn't work well:

```
  @if (empty(Auth::user()->order))
        <blockquote>
            <h1>Sorry you have no order at the moment, would you like to check out our products?</h1>
            <footer><a href="{{route('shop')}}">Click here</a></footer>
        </blockquote>
      @else
.......

@endif
```

user model:

```
public function order(){
       return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

order model:

```
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

my controller that shows orders history view:

```
public function index()
    {
      $user = Auth::user();
      $orders = Order::where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
      return view('users.orders', compact('user', 'orders'));
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by  "it doesn't work well"? What is the structure of your database? Other than that, accessing the model from the view is against the MVC principles, set a boolean in your controller, which indicates the presence or absence of order.

Comment: @DanielAlexandrov I mean it shows my tables instead of showing text (which is in my codes) when user has no order, I want to check logged user id with `order` table and if the logged user id is matches with any of orders in order table show his/her's orders list otherwise show text that s(he) doesn't have any order.

Comment: You can count the orders: Auth::user()->orders->count()

Comment: @M1Ö please make your comment  an answer so i can approve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the orders using:

```
Auth::user()->orders->count()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this working there are a few prerequisite:

1. Have a correct DB schema
2. Have [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) setup (it seems you need [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

If you have this and assuming your relation is setup as:

```
class User extends Model{
    /**
     * Get the orders for the user
     */
    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

You could use the `forelse` blade syntax

```
@forelse (Auth::user()->orders as $order)
    <li>{{ $order->title }}</li>
@empty
    <blockquote>
        <h1>Sorry you have no order at the moment, would you like to check out our products?</h1>
        <footer><a href="{{route('shop')}}">Click here</a></footer>
    </blockquote>
@endforelse
```

This will create a `for` loop in which you could declare the html layout for your order. If there are no orders the `empty` block will instead be used.

Comment: @RobertNicjoo Then you have not setup correct relations I suppose, could you edit your original question to include your user class

Comment: Have you tried debugging output? What does `dd($orders)` in your controller (before the `return` ) yield?

Comment: Already fixed by `@if (Auth::user()->order->count() )` Thanks man. Appreciate it.

Comment: That means that your "error" is just a spelling mistake, my answer would work if you replace `Auth::user()->orders` with `Auth::user()->order`. Glad to help

Comment: your answer has one big issue except miss spelling and that you tried to get loop, and that is `forelse` I'm not sure why but seems laravel doesn't know this query `forelse` ! anyway thank you.

Comment: I’d like to inform you about the [Be nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and [laravel control structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#control-structures) in the second link you can clearly see the loop I was talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150056/discussion-between-milo526-and-robert-nicjoo).