# How to get sessions in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, forms

I bought a Laravel website script, but I want to create a custom form page by myself, and I don't really know how to fetch out data using the session if the user is logged in. Please, can anyone help?

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="{{$user->email}}">
```

How do I add a session so that the input will be able to display the user's email?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269229/how-to-check-current-user-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#retrieving-data)

You can do something like:

```php
$value = $request->session()->get('key');
```

Or even call the global [`session` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/session#the-global-session-helper):

```php
$value = session('key');
```